# Circle with height 100% and matching width

Tags: jquery, css, geometry, aspect-ratio, css-shapes

**What I need is a circle with a height of 100% and a matching width so it makes a proper round circle.**

I need some script that makes the width equal to the height.
I've searched but have not been successful so far.

The *CSS*:

```
.circle1 {
    height: 100%;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

The script:

```
var cw = $('.circle1').width();
    $('.circle1').css({
    'height': cw + 'px'
});
```

But what this does is making the circle 100% screen width just like the height.

Comment: at least show us your html structure or prepare a jsfiddle.net. SO is no place to ask for stuff you need, we can help you with code!

Comment: few questions: what is the parent html structure and are you wrapping your jquery code inside a document ready wrapper?

Comment: I'll just answer them here first if you need code just say so. I'm making a horizontal scroll page, so the .circle1's parent (.main) has a width of 400% (for now) and a height of 100%. The idea is multiple big circles next to each other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this with only CSS using a transparent image with `height:100%; width:auto;`. In the following demo, I used a random tranparent .png  11px*11px but you can use on with 1*1px.

The circle responds to the height of it's container :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/f06aho3r/)**

```css
body,html{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
}
img{
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    border-radius:50%;
    background:teal;
    display:block;
}
div{
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div><img src="http://www.cofetariaonline.ro/images/transparent.png" alt=""></div>
```

Comment: This is exactly what is needed but is there still an option to add content into it? Sorry I'm fairly new to all this...

Comment: Thanks! I think I got it from here

Answer (score 1):

You can use this class to make circles:

```
.circle {
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Created a JS Fiddle for this - http://jsfiddle.net/h0gs54yv/1/

In HTML -

```
<div class="circle"></div>
```

In CSS -

```
html {
    height:100%;
}
body {
    height:100%;
}
.circle {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    border-radius:50%;
    background-color:#f00;
}
```

A little jQuery can hold it's shape on browser resize :)

http://jsfiddle.net/h0gs54yv/2/

Comment: This indeeds makes a perfect circle, but when you resize the browser it's going to be an oval. I need it to stay a perfect circle. If that's possible otherwise i will just roll with this..

Comment: Almost there! Now when the screen is not square it exceeds the 100% height. But if it's not possible to fix that, I can work with this too.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this is what you want:

```
css:
.circle1
{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

Javascript:
$(".circle1").height($(".circle1").width());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dq505nk6/

Comment: This is pretty close to the desired effect. Only that it becomes an oval when resizing. Is there a way for it to keep adjusting it's width to the height, and not only on page load?